# Запускает ли Task.Wait() задачу

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task

Осторожно, ниже костыль и использование Task не по назначению:

```
class MyObject { }
class MyClass
{
  public MyObject myobject;
  public Task<MyObject> TaskMyObject;
  public MyClass()
  {
    TaskMyObject = new Task<MyObject>(GetMyObject);
  }
  public MyObject GetMyObject() => myobject;
  public void parentResume() => TaskMyObject.Start(); //тут косяк
  public void parentResumeNew() //тут косяк
  {
     try
     {
        TaskMyObject.Start();
     }
     catch(Exception ex) { ExceptionToLog(ex); }
  }

}

void SendToController(MyClass _MyClass) //выполняется в отдельном потоке
{
  //Do something
  _MyClass.myobject = //set something
  _MyClass.parentResume();
}

public (bool, MyObject) Execute()
{
  MyClass _MyClass = new MyClass();
  SendToController(_MyClass); //код метода SendToController выполняется в отдельном потоке
  bool time_success = _MyClass.TaskMyObject.Wait(delay);
  return (time_success, _MyClass.myobject);
}
```

Суть кода:

1. Принять Execute()
2. Отослать в контроллер (который крутит отдельный поток) задачу MyClass через SendToController
3. Запустить Wait для ожидания завершения операции
4. Контроллер выполняет задачу из MyClass, записывает в него ответ MyObject
5. Контроллер возобновляет работу метода Execute вызовом parentResume()
6. TaskMyObject.Wait() ждёт либо возобновления через parentResume(), либо таймаута
7. Execute() возвращает ответ - был ли превышен delay и ответ MyObject

Писал этот код давно (больше 2х лет назад), раньше он работал как часы, на потоках с бесконечным таймаутом, мьютексах - получалось не так эффективно, поэтому использовал Task. Т.е. Task используется исключительно как пауза с автовозобновлением.
Вчера произошёл вылет с ошибкой `System.InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a task that was already started.` в `parentResume() => TaskMyObject.Start();`
До этого всё работало без малейших заиканий.

После чего я добавил метод `parentResumeNew()` и использовал его вместо `parentResume()` и теперь `Start may not be called on a task that was already started.` я вижу в логе довольно часто. Но, несмотря на это, ответ MyObject я получаю корректно.

В связи с чем у меня возникает вопрос: не запускает ли Task.Wait() задачу (есть ли внутри `Task.Start()`), и если да - то как сделать ожидание ответа (обработок в SendToController) или таймаута через Task без возобновления работы Execute раньше времени?
Или проблема вообще в другом месте?

Comment: `Start()` просто запускает код делегата. Повторный вызов `Start()` раньше ничего не делал, а теперь бросает исключение. Но я так и не понял, что это за зверь и какую задачу он решает. В любом случае оно "работало" не так как вам казалось. `Wait()` ничего никогда не запускал и не запускает. Он просто вешает текущий поток.

Comment: @aepot >>``Wait() ничего никогда не запускал`` - это отлично, значит у меня где-то повторный вызов resume.

Comment: @aepot зверь (тут обрезанная его версия) решает задачу предоставления задания, полученного из сети, к внешнему устройству через череду потоков и возвращает ответ или таймаут: ``API1(thread1) -> Execute(thread1) -> SendToController(thread2) -> API2(thread2) -> parentResume(thread3) -> Execute(thread1) -> API1(thread1)`` Просто на момент создания франкенштейна через мьютексы ничего не получалось, а созданный вручную поток оставался висеть в случае ошибки на участке SendToController(DoSomething), чем вызывал утечку памяти. Бесконечный цикл с ручным токеном жрал кучу ресурсов, только с Task всё ок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start()` просто запускает код делегата. Повторный вызов `Start()` раньше ничего не делал, а теперь бросает исключение. Но я так и не понял, что это за зверь и какую задачу он решает. В любом случае оно "работало" не так как вам казалось. `Wait()` ничего никогда не запускал и не запускает. Он просто вешает текущий поток.

Этот код легко дописать до более вменяемого состояния:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _lock = new ManualResetEventSlim();
  
    public void Resume() => _lock.Set();

    public void Wait(int delay)
    {
        _lock.Reset();
        _lock.Wait(delay);
    }
}
```

То есть оно будет либо ждать `delay,` либо до вызова `Resume()`.

Ну или если хочется вообще красиво, то вот так:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _lock = new ManualResetEventSlim();
  
    public void Resume() => _lock.Set();

    public void Wait(int delay)
    {
        _lock.Reset();
        _lock.Wait(delay);
    }

    public void Dispose() => _lock.Dispose();
}
```

При чем, здесь можно вообще не париться о повторном вызове `Resume()`, он здесь допустим и является нормальным.

Можно такую же штуку через `CancellationToken`+`Task.Delay` провернуть, если вам вдруг захочется `await`.

Comment: ``ManualResetEventSlim.Wait`` не жрёт ресурсы при ожидании? Если в методе, в котором вызывается Wait произойдёт ошибка (закроется сетевой сокет), то как должно работать высвобождение ресурсов?

Comment: @Blackmeser ничего он не жрет. Это обычный `WaitHandle`. Про исключение не понял, но кажется если возникает исключение, то выполнение кода дальше не идет, если конечно оно возникло прямо в текущем потоке. Если где-то там, то где-то там и упадет.

Comment: @Blackmeser по поводу `Task`, посмотрите еще примеры создания и завершения таска с использованием `TaskCompletionSource`. Возможно это тоже в тему. Там вообще без делегатов можно результат в `Task<T>` положить. Если надо, могу пример нарисовать.

Comment: Спасибо, не нужно, я уже разобрался, просто был множественный вызов ``parentResume()``, от которого к сожалению не уйти. Отловил с помощью ``Environment.StackTrace``. Пофиксил добавлением ``bool resumed`` в ``MyClass`` и проверкой ``if (resumed) return;`` в ``parentResume()``, с предохранителем в виде try-catch всё это хорошо работает. С вашим примером на ``ManualResetEventSlim`` буду экспериментировать, ибо нужно думать как его встроить, т.к. тут для примера приводил облегчённую версию, а в проекте тонны кода.

Comment: ещё раз спасибо за решение. Дошли руки использовать данный подход на деле, работает великолепно и без костылей. Смотрю исходный код класса `ManualResetEventSlim` и вижу что используется Windows Native API чтобы создать данный Event, что внутри класса. Но под Linux данный подход тоже работает. Что там по факту под капотом? Мьютексы?

Comment: @Blackmeser без понятия, что там, в тех же исходниках должно быть видно.